# How to get $ to print out on the screen?

Tags: assembly

I wanted to know how in assembly language you would get an output like
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE$EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE$
and also just output $ itself.

Comment: you may look at an ascii table and  emit corresponding  code. but you should precise the processor and os and show us what you tried since now ?

Comment: First, assembly is meaningless without the architecture. How can I know which assembly language are you using? Second, stackoverflow is not for requesting. You must show what you've done and the problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're targeting MS-DOS, use interrupt 21H, function AH=2 - single character output. Place the ASCII code for the $ sign (that's 24h) into DL.

```
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 24h
int 21h
```

$ only matters for function AH=9, the one that outputs a string. This one outputs a single character, and $ has no special meaning to it.

In order to output a whole string that may contain embedded $'s, roll your own loop.

Comment: I'm just assuming here, But since in DOS assembly $ is the string terminator, I'm not sure it would actually print out?

Comment: $ only matters for function AH=9, the one that outputs a string. This one outputs a single character, and $ has no special meaning to it.

Comment: Ahh of course. I knew AH=2 outputted a character but I wasn't sure if it cared about $ or not.
Of course though it would make no sense if it did.